# Android - Having trouble with calling a service from an action button of a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I want to be able to have a button that copies the text from a notification to the clipboard. The notification is sent through the google's GCM service.

The first time the notification arrives when I press the "copy" button everything is fine and the text goes into the clipboard by the service that the button sends an intent to. The second time a notification arrives with different text when I press the "copy" button the content of the first notification goes into the clipboard instead of the new one. When I debug the code, it seems that the intent that's calling the service has the new content, but the service that puts it into the clipboard runs with the parameters of the old notification, as if the same session of the service is awaken with the old intent.

Any clue why this is happening?

```
// Called by the GCM notification handler

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, clipboardService.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("tool",msg);
    PendingIntent serviceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                    .setContentTitle("Here's your text!")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm, "Copy", serviceIntent); // <--- The intent will have the right (new) value on the second run
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

This is the service that the notification actions calls to:

```
public class clipboardService extends IntentService {
public clipboardService() {
    super("clipboardService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) { //This intent will have the values of the first intent to fire, instead of the updated one.
    String msg = (String) intent.getExtras().get("tool");
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("2android",msg);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is very late to answer your question, but recently I faced the same issue and Google led to me this unanswered question. So here is my understanding if in future someone dig this up.

This is because `PendingIntent` uses cached intent extras from previous instance of the intent unless you explicitly tell it not to. There are two ways to do that...

1. Use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` or `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (best in your case) as flag while constructing the `PendingIntent`. The first flag will automatically dismiss the previous `PendingIntent` and create a completely new one and the second one will only update the extras for the `PendingIntent` and save the overhead of creating a completely new one.

   ```
   PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, notificationIntent, 
                            FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT |  FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   ```
2. Pass an unique `requestCode` to the `PendingIntent` constructor everytime. This will generate unique pending intents for everytime so that you can access the extras associated with a particular intent later. I believe this is not required in your case.

   ```
   PendingIntent.getService(this, UNIQUE_ID, pi, 0);
   ```